# filesize function fails when run from cron

Tags: php, cron

I get the below error when I run my scrip from `cron`

> **Warning**:  filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for /home2/sharingi/public_html/scrape/zip/dailydose/April_14_2011.zip in **/home2/sharingi/public_html/scrape/zip/zip.php**

However if I run the script from my browser it works fine. Some kind of a permissions problem?

Comment: are `cron` and your web-server process using the same user?

Comment: not sure. it's shared hosting. how would i check?

Comment: make cron run `whoami` and email you the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably an issue related to the user that your cron process runs under. Make sure that whatever cron runs as has permissions, since it's probably not the same user as your ssh account or the webserver account. You can probably figure out which user cron runs as by configuring cron to run the command `whoami` and email you the output.

If you can't figure out how to make that work, you might try configuring cron to `wget` the public url that you know works. Don't forget to turn off the file saving, and set it to quiet mode, otherwise you'll get a lot of garbage from each run.

Answer (score 0):

if you're in a shared hosting environment, your `cron` job is probably running as your own user, so unless you yourself don't have read permissions for the file in question, I imagine that's probably not the issue.

As a probable work-around, in case you can't get to the bottom of it easily, [here's a function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#102135) which should allow you to get the info you need without using the php-builtin.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to give that function a try if I could not get `filesize()` working.